# Recommended way to realise bidirectional visibility in C++

Tags: inheritance, constructor, reference, c++14, smart-pointers

I wonder what is this recommended way to what I consider bidirectional visibility between a class instance and its members in C++ 14.

As an example, let's assume I want to write a class **World** which is populated with different kinds of people. So **World** holds a std::vector>. Person should be an abstract base class, with pure virtual functions implemented in **PersonOne** and **PersonTwo**. Now I want to allow person instances to be able to access their world, including other persons.

My first approach would be to pass the world as a **reference** to **this** in the world's constructor. However, I'm not sure if this could get me into trouble. Ideally, I would like to have this self-contained, i.e. the world including the people within should be fully initialised in the world's constructor, and it should be possible to copy-construct a world without tweaking the people's properties within separately. Smart pointers seem not to be a viable alternative as I couldn't create a shared_ptr to this in the world's constructor and pass it to their people's members.

```
class Person{
    public:
    World &world;

    Person(World &_w):world(_w){};
};

class PersonOne: public Person{

    public: 
    PersonOne(World &_w):Person(_w);
};

class PersonTwo: public Person{

    public: 
    PersonTwo(World &_w):Person(_w){};

};

class World{
    public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>> people;

    World(){
        people.push_back(std::make_unique<PersonOne>(*this));
        people.push_back(std::make_unique<PersonTwo>(*this));
    }; 
};
```

Comment: The problem can be when you inherit another class from `World`.

Comment: Use `std::reference_wrapper<World>` as a member in `Person`. You can just pass `this` to `Person`'s constructor, and then initialise the `std::reference_wrapper<World>` member in `person` with `std::ref`.

Comment: @cantordust: how is this an improvement? Up to this point, I thought that std::reference_wrapper was mainly used to use references e.g. in containers, so I don't see the use here where I could just use a normal reference.

Comment: @Chris You can reassign a `std::reference_wrapper`, but you can't do that with a plain reference. That in turn allows you to copy your `World`s. In addition, you can create a `std::reference_wrapper<World>` by simply passing `World&` to `Person`'s constructor. As you mentioned, you can't create a `std::shared_ptr<World>` like that.

Answer (score 1):

Copying is tricky in this situation as you would always have to make sure that `Person`s refer to the right `World`. One option is to ensure that you have custom copy constructors and `operator=` in `World`, where you can call a function to update your population. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using uint = unsigned int;

class World;
using WorldRef = std::reference_wrapper<World>;

class Person
{
    WorldRef world;
    std::string name;
    friend class World;
public:

    Person(World& _world,
           const std::string& _name)
        :
          world(_world),
          name(_name)
    {}
};

class World
{
    uint year;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Person> population;
    friend class Person;

    void init()
    {
        for (auto& p : population)
        {
            /// Note: This is necessary, otherwise this world's
            /// inhabitants will refer to the wrong world.
            /// Call this function from each constructor and
            /// assignment operator.
            p.world = std::ref(*this);
        }
    }

public:

    World(const uint _year,
          const World& _other,
          const std::string& _name)
        :
          year(_year),
          population(_other.population),
          name(_name)
    {
        init();
        std::cout << "It is now " << year << "\n"
                  << "Melon Tusk has built a rocket allowing cheap interplanetary travel.\n";
        for (auto& p : population)
        {
            std::cout << p.name << " has moved to " << p.world.get().name << "\n";
        }
    }

    World(const uint _year,
          const std::string& _name,
          const uint _pop_size)
        :
          year(_year),
          name(_name),
          population(_pop_size, {*this, "Anonymous " + _name + "ling"})
    {
        init();
        std::cout << "It is " << year << "\n";
        std::cout << name << " has " << population.size() << " inhabitants:\n";
        for (const auto& p : population)
        {
            std::cout << p.name << "\n";
        }
    }

    void operator = (const World& _other)
    {
        population = _other.population;
        init();
    }

    void set_name(const std::string& _name)
    {
        name = _name;
    }

    std::string get_name() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    void add_person(const std::string& _name)
    {
        population.emplace_back(*this, _name);

        std::cout <<_name << " was born on " << name << "\n";
    }

    uint population_size() const
    {
        return population.size();
    }
};

int main()
{
    World earth(2018, "Earth", 5);
    World mars(2025, earth, "Mars");

    mars.add_person("Alice");
    mars.add_person("Bob");
    mars.add_person("Carol");

    World europa = mars;
    europa.set_name("Europa");

    std::cout << "Everyone has moved on to " << europa.get_name() << "\n";

    europa.add_person("David");

    std::cout << europa.get_name() << " has a population of " << europa.population_size() << "\n"
              << "A war is brewing over scant resources.\n"
              << "Such is the nature of humanity.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
It is 2018
Earth has 5 inhabitants:
Anonymous Earthling
Anonymous Earthling
Anonymous Earthling
Anonymous Earthling
Anonymous Earthling
It is now 2025
Melon Tusk has built a rocket allowing cheap interplanetary travel.
Anonymous Earthling has moved to Mars
Anonymous Earthling has moved to Mars
Anonymous Earthling has moved to Mars
Anonymous Earthling has moved to Mars
Anonymous Earthling has moved to Mars
Alice was born on Mars
Bob was born on Mars
Carol was born on Mars
Everyone has moved on to Europa
David was born on Europa
Europa has a population of 9
A war is brewing over scant resources.
Such is the nature of humanity.
```

Note how we call `init()` in each constructor and `operator=`. There might be a neater way to do it depending on what you need.

P.S. I am not sure what it means from a logical perspective to *copy* a `World` object as you will end up with clones of your `Person`s. Maybe that is exactly what you want, but I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the constructor issues; I thought of this, but it's probably good for others to have it as reference. And yes, the plan is to clone different worlds including the persons inside to test counterfactuals.

Comment: @Chris Sounds like Total Recall :)